# Maintain hover of an element when another element is hovered

Tags: jquery, css, hover, tooltip, fade

I am using some jquery to fade images in and out on hover.

What happens when the mouse goes over the element the image fades to another image and a tooltip appears directly above the image, the problem is when the mouse leaves the image onto the tooltip the image fades out again. As the tooltip relates to the image I don't want it to fade out until the cursor has left the image or the tooltip.

The code is a little convoluted to show so I created a fiddle of the situation.

So basically I want the image to not fadeback to the original until the mouse has left the image or the associated tooltip.

Thanks for any help!

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/webthread/unUua/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use pure CSS for this. You have to use JavaScript `onmouseover` event to register a hover event, and `onmouseout` to unregister it, or simply ignore it, based on whether you need to maintain the hover effect or not.

Comment: Yeh I had a feeling css wouldn't do it. I couldn't get any js to work though, hence the fiddle ;)